# How do I create custom date intervals for the Slider with Histogram refiner

Tags: 2013, search, refinement-panel

I have a custom field mapped to `RefinableDate02` that contains dates (many of which are dates in the future) I would like to let my users use the slider (with graph) refiner to select date ranges in the future (the out of the box refiner settings only allow dates in the past) I can't find a way to set custom intervals. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up the following article with sample code on creating a custom date range refiner. On the positive side it can be done. On the negative side, it seems like you will be creating labels instead of using the neat slider control.

http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2013/09/27/building-a-sharepoint-2013-search-refiner-with-custom-intervals/

Comment: Thank you Hector! I had gone a different way for that project but I think this will be useful in the future.